# Haskell: Iterating through material in a (complex, recursive) ADT _with context_

Tags: haskell, adt

I have an ADT for, basically, first order logic:

```
data Function = Function String                                             
data Predicate = Predicate String                                           

data Type_ = TPoint | TSet | TFunction | TPositiveRealNumber | TSequence | TNaturalNumber | TGroup

data VariableType = VTNormal | VTDiamond | VTBullet                         

data Dependencies = Dependencies [Term] {-dep-} [Term] {-indep-}            

data Variable = Variable String Int Type_ VariableType Dependencies          

data Term = VariableTerm Variable
          | ApplyFn Function [Term]                                         

data Formula = AtomicFormula Predicate [Term]
             | Not Formula
             | And [Formula]
             | Or [Formula]
             | Forall [Variable] Formula
             | UniversalImplies [Variable] [Formula] Formula
             | Exists [Variable] Formula
```

And I need to iterate through each `Term` (potentially deeply) nested inside a given `Formula` and do something to it -- said thing will depend on both the term and the 'context' in which it appears. So as a simple example we could print out the formula repeatedly, with each copy having a different term bolded.  I don't want this particular behavior wired in; I want a higher-order function with the following type signature

```
f :: (FormulaWithTermShapedHole -> Term -> a) -> Formula -> [a]
```

I  already have a function with this type signature which can do something to every term...

```
mapTermInFormulaM :: Monad m => (Term -> m Term) -> Formula -> m Formula
```

... but it can't utilise context in the way I now need. (So it could print every term that occurs somewhere inside the formula, but it couldn't print the whole formula with the term bolded.)

It feels like there should be a slick way of doing this... any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: For the record, `Type` isn't a reserved word, so you can use `data Type = TPoint | ...` instead of using `Type_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with generic programming in Haskell.
A good starting point for this is:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate

And there are some excellent papers by Simon Peyton Jones who started this, if you want to read further:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/